# LS Factor in SAGA (slope units)

Tags: saga, slope, units, erosion, rusle

In which units do I have to calculate Slope to use as an input for the LS Factor tool in SAGA (degrees, %, radians)?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Slope in **radians** as input raster.

Some hints are in the [code](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/code/ci/master/tree/saga-gis/src/tools/terrain_analysis/ta_hydrology/TopographicIndices.cpp), for instance:

```
Line 567: if( Slope < 0.08975817419 )       // < 9% Steigung := atan(0.09), ca. 5 Degree
```

To be more precise, please also check out any one of the reference paper. For instance:

*Moore, I.D., Grayson, R.B., Ladson, A.R. (1991):* [Digital terrain modelling: a review of hydrogical, geomorphological, and biological applications.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bfbd/cb38c3ad4d86c0ad5c8f3d05db8a4897dfcb.pdf) Hydrological Processes, Vol.5, No.1

The unit is understood when you see the Equation.(8)

[image]

And you can confirm how it is implemented in the LS calculation:

```
Line 536: LS    = (0.4 + 1) * pow(Area / 22.13, 0.4) * pow(sin(Slope) / 0.0896, 1.3)
```

where `Slope` is `beta` in the above.

You may already know SAGA's default output unit of the Slope is *radians*. (It is less intuitive if you are using the tool through QGIS, which default unit is *degrees*.)

Comment: Thank you.   I usually use SAGA tools through QGIS.

Comment: Thanks @Ale ; Sorry if this is an unsought advice - Please be careful about the `Catchment Area`. The input is `specific catchment area` which is an output from `Flow width and Specific Catchment Area` tool.

Comment: @Ale I now feel the note in the code (as referred above) is misleading. It says `9%` but it should have been `0.09 (radians)`.

Comment: Thanks @Kazuhito, I though I had to use Flow accumulation tool. Great advice!