# SAGA or GRASS tools for RUSLE LS factor in QGIS

Tags: grass-gis, saga

I need the LS grid for an area for RUSLE calculation.

I ran both SAGAs `Slope Length` from Terrain Analysis - Hydrology and GRASS's `r.watershed`.

The resulting LS factor grids are completely different. The documentation of both GRASS and SAGA does not describe what calculations these modules are doing. Why are there such stark differences in outputs?

Is SAGA Slope Length output is the same thing as LS factor?

SAGA:
[image]

GRASS:
[image]

Comment: Are you asking about LS-factor or slope length? If you need LS-factor, SAGA has `LS factor` tool in the same Hydrology group. You will just need a set of slope raster and specific catchment area raster.

Comment: @Kazuhito what I need is LS factor, that is used in RUSLE. SAGA has multiple tools for LS factor and they all are producing very very different results. I used `Slope Length` because that is the simplest. Are you saying that it is not LS factor? If it is not, then what is it, because its results are very similar to the Bob Hicky method. Where can I find the description of what each SAGA tool is supposed to do. The official docs has nothing about the purpose of each.

Comment: Yes, they are different. LS factor is based on the Steepness (S) - Slope Length (L) ratio (ref. [LS Factor in SAGA (slope units)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313659/ls-factor-in-saga-slope-units)) while Slope Length (L) itself... ugh... please visit SAGA Team's forum [Slope Length](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/a7bf91b6/).

Comment: @Kazuhito so 1. using Slope Length output for RUSLE is incorrect?
2. Where is the documentation for LS Factor from SAGA as it has many inputs and I am not sure what to provide.

As you can see from other questions on the SE this is all very confusing, can you write a detailed answer on this, if you have time?

Comment: Sorry for this tardy response. 1. You cannot substitute LS-factor with Slope Length in RUSLE calculation. 2. Yes, I will find some time to write a short note. In the meantime, will you try `Basic terrain analysis` tool, which is in the SAGA - Terrain Analysis - Morphometry group? It does all the necessary steps automatically to produce LS-factor.

Comment: Cool. `Basic Terrain Analysis` worked and produced results similar to GRASS but SAGA results look like are based on Multi Direction Flows vs GRASS which produced SFD.

Comment: At least I am comparing apples to apples now. This is what I have understood.
The `slope length` from SAGA is just the L in the LS factor. LS Factor in RUSLE is some combination of both Slope Lenght (L) and Slope Steepness (S). RUSLE needs LS factor so L can't be consumed directly without S. Please point out if my understanding is flawed.

Comment: I am glad to know that `Basic Terrain Analysis` tool worked. And yes, you are quite right about the Slope Length being (L). I think both SAGA and GRASS  (default setting) calculate LS-factor based on MFD, but I may be wrong,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LS-factor is an important variable to estimate average erosion - annual soil loss (as in RUSLE), and based on experimental data. It becomes greater when the slope is steeper and the effective slope length is shorter.
Slope length is the horizontal distance from the ridge to the point where deposition starts to occur. At a given cell, the length to the nearby steepest cell is successively calculated unless all nearby slope is less than half of their own slope.

A suggested overall workflow with a pair of input/output and corresponding SAGA tool are summarized below. As you see, there are many steps and involve several intermediate products.

1. Slope, Aspect, Curvature tool

   Input: DEM

   Output: Slope (measured in radian)
2. Fill Sink (Wang & Liu) tool

   Input: DEM

   Output: DEM without sink
3. Catchment Area tool

   Input: DEM without sink

   Output: Flow Accumulation (Total catchment area)
4. Flow width and specific catchment area tool

   Input: DEM without sink, Flow Accumulation (Total catchment area)

   Output: Specific catchment area
5. LS-factor tool

   Input: Slope, Specific catchment area

   Output: LS-factor

To speed up the process, you can try `Basic terrain analysis` tool, which is in the SAGA - Terrain Analysis - Morphometry group. It does all the necessary steps automatically to produce LS-factor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can SAGA produce LS factor with SFD. Currently, Basic terrain analysis is producing MFD LS Factor.

Comment: @ar-siddiqui I honestly do not know but I guess it is technically possible. The point is to choose MFD (or FD8 in SAGA terminology) in both of `Catchment area` and `Flow width and specific catchment area`  calculations.